# Reference or second name to identify a group of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a second name (but hidden) to each Excel sheet.

Each group of worksheets is related to a different project.

Can I add the project name with VBA? I have two Listbox where you can choose a project name and I want to retrieve all the worksheet names related to the selected project.

Comment: VB.Net <> VBA <> VB6 <> VBScript. They're not the same language just because they all start with VB, any more than a cat, a car and a carrot are all the same because they start with CA. Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your post. Thanks.

Comment: Ok @KenWhite thanks

Comment: There is no *hidden second name* in an Excel workbook. Even if you did hide it inside somewhere, you'd have to open every single workbook to read it anyway. Most places I know use the filename to do what you're asking, such as "ProjectA Something". You can then iterate filenames using a mask, like "ProjectA*.xlsx".

Comment: Hi @KenWhite I want a hidden second name for worksheet not workbook. I have worksheet 1,2...10 and want to put each of this worksheets under one of 3 categories Project 1 2 or 3 as an example sheet 1 5 6 will get the value project 1 and sheets 3 7 9 will get project 2 and the rest project 3. when I open my listboox you'll see project 1 2 or 3 when you select Project 1 you see the names of the sheets that related to this project on the other listbox

Comment: Why not put a hidden worksheet into the workbook, and keep track of which sheet belongs to which project there? When you need to access it, just read the cells from the hidden sheet.

Comment: Take a look at VBA's codename:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel

Comment: Also, you should correct your post title to VBA instead of VB.Net.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks it's a good idea I'll try it

Comment: @DougGlancy thanks for your answer, the code name is unique. I can't work with it

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but if there is a property that is inert (for your purposes), you could hijack that.  For example, if there is no intention of printing the workbook, you could use any of the Worksheet.PageSetup properties.  Or, if it might be printed, you could hide the property in the footer and set the footer margin to nothing.  Again, not a great solution, but a possible hack.  Or, maybe you don't even care if this shows up in the printed output...

Comment: I know i'm late to the game, but you could color code the tabs based on the project.

Comment: It's true that the CodeName isn't unique, but I was imagining different prefixes, e.g., Type1Number1, Type1Number2, Type2Number1...